# Pass an object to a route parameter without model binding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a route like this:

```
Route::post('{object}', 'CommentController@store')->name('store');
```

And I want to pass an object as argument to my form action like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('comment.store', $object) }}" method="post" id="comment--form"></form>
```

#### Here is the problem

if I pass my query object as you know I will get the id of query object
if I pass something like this: `{{ route('comment.store', (new app\anyObject())) }}` I will get exception and for some polymorphism reason I can't use model binding because the object could be any object so I'm wondering if there is any solution for my question

PS
I have a polymorphic comment system and I dont know if it's decoration design pattern or not but I want to save comments dynamically via my interface so I want to save comments dynamically like this:

```
   public function store(Request $request, $object)
    {
        // comments() is an implementation of an interface
        $object->comments()->create([
            'name' => auth()->check() ? $request->user()->fullName() : $request->name,
            'email' => $request->user()->email ?? $request->email,
            'comment' => $request->content,
        ]);
    }
```

But I can't pass an object as argument is there anyway to pass it through route or any other idea or solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't u send your data(`object`) as a parameter containing json_decoded `object` in the request?

Comment: `I will get exception` what is that exception?

Comment: i think better you base64_encode your input, then decode on your method in the controller]. you can't pass any object thingy in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass any object array or form-data in the url . you might want to consider doing base64_encode then decode after in your method. This can solve your issue.

Comment: At that time I though it could be possible